# Joomla: Put Article Image in Head for Facebook

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I would like to extract the article's intro image and insert it into the head for Facebook's og:image metadata. The problem is, I can't seem to get the correct information to fill in. Here's what I've tried...

```
<?php echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$images->image_fulltext.'">';
?>

<?php echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item).'">';
?>
```

Also tried:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$images = json_decode($this->item->images);
$fbimage = JURI::base() . $images->image_fulltext;
$doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $fbimage . '">' );
```

All I get out is `<meta property="og:image" content="">`

What do I need to to to grab the FQDN of either the article image or the intro image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code -

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:image" content="'. Juri::root() . $images->image_fulltext .'">');
```

`Juri::root()` returns the site URL. More detail about [Juri Class](https://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JURI.html)

In order to get intro image or full image path you can refer [this link](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/how-to-get-the-intro-image-of-a-joomla-article).

Comment: That returns `<meta test="og:image" content="http://www.example.org//">`

For some reason, it's not grabbing the URL for `$images->image_fulltext`

Comment: In the head of the template's index.php. There **is** an image in the full_text and intro_text, in the article's settings and it displays in the preview and the article body.

Comment: I figured out the code must be placed into templates\your_template\html\com_content\article\default.php, before the HTML <article> tags, I think you also need to remove `. '/' .` or it will insert an extra / . If you want to include that in your answer.